# How to use of two angular modules?

Tags: angularjs

I add to my page two angularJs elements,

**first** is for uploading files : https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload,

**second** one is a drag and drop menu : https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists ;

Each of them has its js files and angular module, and we know to make our angula app working we have to combine this modules. I tried to make that but it's not working with me. Do you have any idea how to do that ?

Comment: The same way as described in the documentation. If you really want help, you need to show your code, tell us what you expect it to do, and what it does instead. Precisely. With all the relevant error messages.

Comment: Exactly. If you've done everything right in your app, all the answers that'll be posted will be useless if the error is something else entirely.

Comment: I'm just using the github's code of drag menu and fileupload, I didn't do any modification, so when I run the code; I don't have any error. When I run each code seperatly; it's working but when I want to integrate both of them in my page, the menu works but the second one not working and without error message. I hope that I was clear.

Answer (score 1):

Include both modules into your app module. So that you can use both modules in your app.

```
angular.module('your_app', [
    'blueimp.fileupload',
    'dndLists'
])
```

Comment: I tried that and I had 2 errors : 1- Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod]  ; 2-Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Comment: will you please share your code? only the portion code where you injected these dependencies

Comment: Honestly, I don't know when I have to put these dependencies; so I create a new js file and I added to my page; I'm beginner in AngularJS :)

Comment: Cool. but if you share that portion like that I shared above. I can edit that.

Comment: app.js (Files upload) : (function () {
    'use strict';
    var isOnGitHub = window.location.hostname === 'blueimp.github.io',
        url = isOnGitHub ? '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/' : 'server/php/';
    angular.module('demo', [
        'blueimp.fileupload'
    ])
        .config([
            '$httpProvider', 'fileUploadProvider',
            function ($httpProvider, fileUploadProvider) {
                delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];  ....ETC

Comment: nested.js (dnd menu) : angular.module("app").controller("NestedListsDemoController", function($scope) {

    $scope.models = {
        selected: null,
        templates: [
            {type: "item", id: 2},
            {type: "container", id: 1, columns: [[], []]}
        ],
....ETC

Comment: view-source.js (dnd menu) : angular.module("app").directive('viewSource', function($http, $timeout) {
    return {
        scope: {
            demoName: "@viewSource",
            highlightLines: "="
        },
        templateUrl: 'framework/vendor/view-source.html', 
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attr) {

            scope.models = {
                types: [
                    {extension: "html", language: "markup", label: "Markup"},
                    {extension: "css", language: "css", label: "CSS"} ...ETC

Comment: demo-framework.js (dnd menu) : angular.module("app", ["ngRoute", "dndLists"])
    .config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/nested', {
                templateUrl: 'nested/nested-frame.html',
                controller: 'NestedListsDemoController'
            })
           
            .otherwise({redirectTo: '/nested'});
    })
....ETC

Comment: Syam Pillai that's the all js that I'm working with , so I add a new file named "Myapp.js" : angular.module('Myapp', [
    'blueimp.fileupload',
    'dndLists'
]); and then in my page index.html I add it with <script src="Myapp.js"></script> and it doesn't work as I said before